# JAVA - Access Methods and Classes from another Class

Tags: java, netbeans

So far i got this:

```
package hotel;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Hotel {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
Prices describe1 = new Prices();
Scanner user_in = new Scanner(System.in);
String method;

System.out.println("Welcome to Hotel HIV!");
System.out.println("We are happy to see that you would like to stay with    us.");
System.out.println("Please, type which room you would like to book: ");
System.out.println("Single Bed, Double Bed, President Suit");
method = user_in.nextLine();

if ("Single Bed".equals(method)) {
    System.out.println(Prices.describe1);
} else {
    System.out.println("Please choose one of the rooms above.");
    }
  }
}
```

And the second class is :

```
package hotel;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author Defalt
*/
public class Prices {
Scanner user_in = new Scanner(System.in);
int price1 = 300;
int price2 = 600;
int price3 = 2500;

class describe1 {      
System.out.println("You Choose the Single Bed.");
System.out.println("This room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge but no View on  the Ocean.");
System.out.println("This room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.");
System.out.println("Would you like to book this room?");
  }
}
```

As you can see i just want to make a non-GUI hotel reservation program for 3 rooms.

My question:

How can i access the "describe" parameters on the second class so that i can just link them into the main function. If i do public void describe1() it says in the main that "no void is allowed here".

Comment: You cannot have statements out of a method, put all prints inside a method. I advise you to read a [basic Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to understand the very basics of the language.

Comment: Also you just call the name of the method when you try to execute it, with brackets and parameters

Comment: And think of a better name for your hotel too.. not much business otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers already point out, `describe1` needs to be a method instead of a class. And as method it needs to be `static` or called on an object instance.

You use `describe1()` as a parameter to `println`. In this case it must not return void. You have two options.

In both cases you create an instance first:

```
 Prices prices = new Prices();
```

You already do that in your code with the confusing name describe1. I assume the name prices here, so that object instance and method have a different name. This is not a requirement, it is just for easier recognition which is which.

Option 1: make describe1 return a String.

```
public String describe1() {
    return "You chose ....\nThis room Contains....";
}
```

and keep calling it by

```
System.out.println(prices.describe1());
```

Option 2: let the method do the output and just call it

```
if ("Single Bed".equals(method)) {
   prices.describe1();
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: that worked great, also helped me understand what was wrong / missing.

though u said it doesnt have to be 'prices' yet if i name it something else i have to change the class name or create new one right?

as my first attempt to name it 'describe1' was, to try and access the 'describe1' itself.

Comment: The name of a variable can be chosen independent of its class or its methods. `describe1` would have perfectly worked, I just felt it would clear some confusion to have a different object and method name, since you'd have to call it as `describe1.describe1()` otherwise. While it's common in simple cases to name the object after its class, this is far from a requirement. Also be aware that Java is case dependant, so to the compiler `prices` (lower case) and `Prices` (upper case) are completely different identifiers.

Comment: ah damn, now i understand. i was nearly there the first time i did it (before i posted here) i just didnt do `public String xxx` instead i used a said void. Now its clear. Only thing left to do is to make a room - used - if he wants to book another room. i know here its not good to go off topic nor say thank you, but for manners sake

thank you for your help and your fast respond time!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
System.out.println(Prices.describe1);
```

becomes

```
System.out.println(new Prices().describe1());
```

And

```
class describe1 {      
    System.out.println("You Choose the Single Bed.");
    System.out.println("This room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge but no View on  the Ocean.");
    System.out.println("This room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to book this room?");
}
```

becomes

```
public void describe1() {      
    System.out.println("You Choose the Single Bed.");
    System.out.println("This room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge but no View on  the Ocean.");
    System.out.println("This room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to book this room?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't you mean to write:

```
// This is a (public) method of hotel.Prices
public void describe1()
{      
    System.out.println("You Choose the Single Bed.");
    System.out.println("This room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge but no View on  the Ocean.");
    System.out.println("This room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to book this room?");
}
```

instead of:

```
 // This is a inner (non-static nested) class...you must have a (public) method to write the "printing logic"...
 class describe1 
 {      
     System.out.println("You Choose the Single Bed.");
     System.out.println("This room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge but no View on  the Ocean.");
     System.out.println("This room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.");
     System.out.println("Would you like to book this room?");
  }
```

Hope it helps.